# How do I run a PowerShell script even if Set-ExecutionPolicy is banned?

Tags: java, powershell

The Set-ExecutionPolicy command of PowerShell is banned, so I can NOT run like this:

```
PS> .\script.ps1 (enter)
```

Is there another way to run the PowerShell script except from the "Windows PowerShell ISE"?

PS: I was able to use Java's ProccessBuilder to run a single PowerShell command, but don't know how to run the whole script.

Comment: https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/ ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is what we use to run PowerShell scripts from Java (works regardless of the execution policy):

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File <script_name>
```

Comment: If one can just bypass the execution policy from the command line, what's the point of setting it at all?

Comment: @EricJ. - i think the point is that you are running from the command line.  an automatically executing script would not have the ability to manipulate the command line, and therefore would be subject to the current policy.  a program which has access to the command line presumably already has full access within the limits of the current account.

Comment: @jtahlborn I mean... couldn't you just write a `.bat` that has that exact call to `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`, then wouldn't that count as automatically executing?

Comment: @KolobCanyon - sure, and you can write a bat file that can delete the contents of your user directory.  i'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: @jtahlborn I guess my question is, if somebody double clicks a `.ps1` file and the `Execution Policy == Restricted` does that mean script cannot run? Versus if you wrap it in a `.bat` file with your command above, you could override the execution policy? Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

The <strike>easiest</strike> silliest way around this is just:

```
gc .\script.ps1 | iex
```

This works in PowerShell and doesn't care about `ExecutionPolicy`. Just make sure that you are careful with newlines. Keep `{}`s and similar on the same line, using `;`s where needed.

Comment: An alternative way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6):

[Oisin Grehan has an interesting post on his blog](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2012/02/10/Bypassing-Restricted-Execution-Policy-in-Code-or-in-Script) which provides another way to bypass the execution policy. Open a shell and run this:

```
function Disable-ExecutionPolicy {
    ($ctx = $executioncontext.gettype().getfield(
        "_context", "nonpublic,instance").getvalue(
            $executioncontext)).gettype().getfield(
                "_authorizationManager", "nonpublic,instance").setvalue(
        $ctx, (new-object System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager
                  "Microsoft.PowerShell"))
}
Disable-ExecutionPolicy
```

This removes the default host authorization manager which will allow you to call scripts from that shell. You'd have to run this for each shell you open though since the execution policy is only overridden in the shell in which this is run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight enhancement to Andy's answer to this question. If an admin sets a restrictive PowerShell script execution policy in a GPO (probably under the mistaken notion that PowerShell execution policy is a security boundary), you can get a PowerShell interactive session that has execution policy disabled by using the following command line:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 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 -NoExit
```

The `-EncodedCommand` here is the following code:

```
function Disable-ExecutionPolicy{($ctx=$ExecutionContext.GetType().GetField("_context","nonpublic,instance").GetValue($ExecutionContext)).GetType().GetField("_authorizationManager","nonpublic,instance").SetValue($ctx,(New-Object Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager "Microsoft.PowerShell"))};Disable-ExecutionPolicy;if(Test-Path $PROFILE){. $PROFILE}
```

That is, disable the execution policy by running the function described in Andy's answer, and then dot-source the current user profile script if it exists.