# Run PowerShell as administrator and a different user

Tags: powershell, administrator, runas

In my company I used to code on one of our [domain controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller) (DCs) with Windows Server 2012. However since I can not do it there anymore, I am now forced to code on my workstation using my normal user account instead of my domain administrator account.

The problem I encountered now was that when I run PowerShell as administrator I can use "Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted", but I don't have full access to our DFS filesystem since I am not the domain administrator with this account.
When I start PowerShell as the domain administrator I can not set the execution policy since I didn't run PowerShell as administrator.

How can I run PowerShell as administrator and domain administrator?

Comment: Add the Domain Admins group to Local Administrators.

Comment: I did. but when i run as my dom admin acc and try to set exec policy it says:

Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  unrestricted
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

Comment: What if you did something like this instead with your powershell call? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271681/how-to-run-powershell-script-even-if-set-executionpolicy-is-banned

Comment: "I can not set the execution policy since I didn't run PowerShell as administrator" - yes you can. Just specify the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter on the `powershell.exe` command line.